# Magento Review stars showing Empty in product

Tags: magento

After reviewing the product I've just approved and on a single product page it shows comments but the rating star is not showing.

```
<?php $_votes = $_review->getRatingVotes(); ?>
                    <?php if (count($_votes)): ?>
                    <table class="ratings-table">
                        <col width="1" />
                        <col />
                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach ($_votes as $_vote): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_vote->getRatingCode()) ?></th>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="rating-box">
                                        <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $_vote->getPercent() ?>%;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: this issue is with a particular product or other products as well?

Comment: each and every product have same problem

Comment: star are displayed using background image, check if that image is available or not on the path

Comment: Okay but if i select only 4 stars it show with as 40% <div class="rating" style="width:80%;"></div>

Comment: 4 out of 5, then it has set correct width (80%) , whats wrong in it?